# Defining arbitrary order derivatives function

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

I have a function $\phi(t)$ and I want to define a function $\phi D(t,r):=\phi^{(r)}(t)$, in other words evaluate the $r$'th derivative of $\phi$ at $t$. The naive code that I have is:

`phiD[t_, r_] = D[phi[t], {t, r}]`

which doesn't work, because Mathematica doesn't know to evaluate the $r$ part first and then the $t$ part. What's the easiest way to implement this?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is that you face. If you dart, say, with `phi[t_] := Sin[t]^5 Cos[t]^3`, then `phiD[t_, r_] = D[phi[t], {t, r}]` returns essentially `D[Cos[t]^3*Sin[t]^5, {t, r}]`. And then `phiD[t, 6]` will give the correct 6th derivative as a function of `t`; you may then replace `t` with any particular numeric value.

Comment: @murray: If you put in 'phiD[1,6]' you will get an error that '1' is not a valid variable. I am using Mathematica 9.

Comment: @Artes: In the answers to the linked question, I don't see $s$ being substituted for a number anywhere. For example in the accepted answer, there's still the free variable $s$ that was differentiated in. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Artes: Derivative seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly as to be expected: if you put in a constant for the variable `t` in `phiD[t_, r_] = D[phi[t], {t, r}]`, you're asking to take the `t`th derivative of a constant rather than of a function depending on a variable. And you're solution provided as an Answer certainly avoids that. I just wasn't clear what the original problem was.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments, Artes suggested the Derivative function. This works:

`phiD[t_,r_]=Derivative[r][phi][t]`